# Starting a chrome address bar google search with "c#" now changes the string to "c/#"

Tags: c#, google-chrome, url

This only started happening in the last couple of months, and typing c/# into the address bar tries to go to that url rather than doing a search.

I know it's not really a programming question, but I start a lot of searches with "c#"!

I had a look through chrome's settings but couldn't find anything relevant, anyone know a was to avoid chrome adding the '/'?

Comment: Not really anything to do with programming in c#.

Comment: @BenRobinson although I expect every C# programmer who has this issue is likely to come here to find the answer (e.g. me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be the prediction service is enabled in your Chrome browser. This is done by default.

To disable it:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar (upper right).
2. Select Settings.
3. Click Show advanced settings.
4. In the "Privacy" section, deselect the "Use a prediction service to
   help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" checkbox.
5. You should then also clear your browser history.

This is for browser history: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95537.

This is what I found after research.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the question asked. The prediction service only helps with auto-completion while typing in searches in the address bar.

Comment: @Zack I didn't want to turn off this check box, but I do that because of you. This fix the problem. Please next time check it before writing a comment. Ok, thank you !

Comment: Yeah confirm that works too! I tried to google the issue, but must have been using the wrong search terms.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what the issue actually was. Are you saying that you would start typing a search in the address bar, then when you clicked on one of the predictions that showed up, it would try to go to a website, and fail?

Comment: @Michael Yeah, this doesn't actually solve any problems. It just stops you from selecting a prediction that was not correct. If you type in "c# programming" in the address bar, you can see that the first prediction it shows is for a web page, because the icon is a page, just like on https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en shows. If you want to perform a search in the address bar, you should put the "?" in front of your search.

Answer (score 20):

If you put a `?` at the beginning of your search in the address bar, it will perform a search, even if you typed in a url.

You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to set the focus to the address bar with the `?` already added for you.

For example, if you type "c# programming" into the address bar when you have predictions enabled, the first result is a web site link to "c/# programming" which doesn't exist.

[image: Prediction results]

If you put the "?" before your search text, you will get a list of search term auto-completion suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's been annoying me for ages.

Comment: s/ages/a few months/

Comment: This has been driving me crazy since I started using C#, thanks a lot!